# can we use select...into command in create table in mysql 5.7?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.7

I'm using mysql server 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04 lts, I want to create a table which uses values from other tables. I tried using select...into while creating the table, but failed. I created table as below.

```
mysql> create table BILLING_PRODUCTS_DETAILS
    -> (
    -> bill_Number int not null,
    -> product_id int not null,
    -> unit_Price decimal(8,2) not null,
    -> purchase_Quantity int default 1,
    -> purchase_Quantity_Price decimal(10,2) not null,
    -> foreign key (bill_Number) references BILL_HEADER(bill_Number),
    -> foreign key (product_Id) references PRODUCT_DETAILS(product_Id),
    -> select product_Price into unit_Price from PRODUCTS_DETAILS where product_Id = PRODUCTS_DETAILS.product_Id,
    -> select (purchase_Quantity * unit_Price) into purchase_Quantity_Price
    -> );

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select product_Price into unit_Price from PRODUCTS_DETAILS where product_Id = PR' at line 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a better option. You first create the table and then update it. It's simple right.